# Can't uninstall SpecFlow plugin from VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uninstallation, specflow

I installed it and don't use it anymore but could not Uninstall it.  I did run VS10 as an Administrator and the button Uninstalled is still greyed out.  All my other VS10 plugins are shown with their uninstalled buttons available.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some extensions do - for some reason - have the same greyed out uninstall button as you mention here when running VS2010.

However, there's also small text at the bottom of the window for these extensions saying "You need to use Windows Add/Remove Programs to remove this extension."

It's a bit odd but I expect it is because certain VS2010 extensions require additional installation behaviour that can't be cleaned up from within the VS2010 extension manager.